# How to Draw Curved progress charts in mql4?

Tags: mql4, metatrader4, mt4

Sorry for the weird post title , I dont really know what to call this it , looks like a curved progress bar or half pie chart but dont really know the name of this type of charts.

Do any body know how to draw curved progress bar in mql4 like the one in the image below  :

[Here is the screenshot please have a look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5ist.jpg)

not really interested in the whole combo box , just looking for a way to draw that curved (pink and blue) bar
I was hoping to draw something like this in mt4 EA or indicator
but I dont really know where to start ,

hence I am asking if anybody know anything about these charts it will be highly appreciated if you can share some information about it.

Comment: That looks like it's been created using a custom dll. There are no native functions in MQL4 that could create this.

Answer (score 0):

you can use mql standard library called canvas .